# I have a problem loading my website NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have an application developed in NextJS and deployed in Vercel. The problem I have is that Vercel's performance analytics give me very low results and I don't understand why.

The images are compressed, could it be some component rendering issue? The page is very simple, the only interaction there is a contact form that sends an email.

Could someone give me an idea of ​​what can happen?

The website in question is: avocat-asmaekirimov.com

This is Vercel's score:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVWPP.png)

I have tried to solve it by compressing images, optimizing the CSS but it is not such a big application

Answer (score 0):

- share the website url please so we could check in more details.
- try to change your server on vercel    (https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/regions)

there are many senarios that ccould make this happened. so please provide more information